# How to resolve error ORA-19802 when starting up an Oracle database instance?

Tags: oracle, startup

I tried starting up my instance and received the error ORA-19802. Cannot use `db_recovery_file_dest` without `db_recovery_file_dest_size`. How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Did you have a chance to look up the error code in the manual?

Answer (score 1):

Answer here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2203255

reference answer:

You can always export, edit and import a pfile, even when the instance won't start like this:

```
SQL> create pfile = '/tmp/pfile' from spfile='+DATA/rac/spfilerac.ora';
```

edit the pfile with the text editor of your choice and import back:

```
SQL> create spfile='+DATA/rac/spfilerac.ora' from pfile='/tmp/pfile';**
```